# Cannot configure synonym for an index

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to configure `synonym` for an index ; through `Elasticvue` I run this :

```
HTTP method : PUT , Path : /my_index

Request body :

{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "synonym": {
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "synonym"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "synonym": {
                        "type": "synonym",
                        "synonyms_path": "synonym.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
                "reason": "index [my_index/F5AydksvQy2hzXNV1BnyWg] already exists",
                "index_uuid": "F5AydksvQy2hzXNV1BnyWg",
                "index": "my_index"
            }
        ],
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [my_index/F5AydksvQy2hzXNV1BnyWg] already exists",
        "index_uuid": "F5AydksvQy2hzXNV1BnyWg",
        "index": "my_index"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

So how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to delete your index and then create it again with your new index setting.

You're getting the error `resource_already_exists_exception` because you are trying to create an index while the older index still exists.

Comment: In fact the index is created automatically in my Symfony project : 
`$this->elasticclient = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts([$esUrl])->build();
$client = $this->elasticclient;
$client->index($params);`
So how can I configure it in this case ?

Comment: @pheromix I am not familiar with Symfony. But in elasticsearch, if you need to configure a synonym for an index, then that is done at the creation time itself. Or else you need to delete the index and recreate it with a new index setting.